# Как достать из JSON строку и файл? (java)

Tags: javascript, java, json

Значит в JS запаковываю изображение и нужную мне строку отправляю как json:

```
var form = document.forms[2];
var formData = new FormData(form);
var json = {
    "id": id,
    "file": formData
};
$.ajax( "URL", {
    data: JSON.stringify(json),
    type: "post",
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (data) {
        if(data == true){
            window.location.reload();
        }
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("Ошибка!");
    }
});
```

А на стороне RestControllera не получается достать эти данные.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save-avatar", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public boolean saveUserAvatar(@RequestBody String data){
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(data);
    int id = Integer.valueOf(json.getString("id"));
    MultipartFile multipartFile = (MultipartFile) json.get("file");
}
```

точнее строка достается, а файл нет.

Если из JS отправлять только один файл то на стороне контроллера я достаю его таким образом:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "change-avatar", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody void changeAvatar(MultipartHttpServletRequest request){

    MultipartFile multipartFile = request.getFile("file");

}
```

Как достать и строку и файл на стороне контроллера?

Comment: Строку записать в `formData` и отправлять `formData`, а не `json`.

Comment: А вы попробуйте вывести сформированный json в консоль и посмотрите, что в поле `file`.

Comment: Спасибо. добавил строку в formanData и все заработало